# esp32 , thingsboard rpc , request timeout

Tags: esp32, thingsboard

I've recently started using esp32 wrover for a university exam/project.
I'm try to control a servo from my thingsboard dashboard (I'm using community edition), but when I do the RPC it doesn't work and I have a request timeout...I really can't figure out why it isn't working.
I wrote my code following another example that I had that worked.

If someone could help me find the error it would be great!

Sorry if my english isn't the best and if I didn't use the right technical words! I'll try to work on this.......

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>


#define SERVO_PIN 15

#include <ThingsBoard.h>

constexpr char WIFI_SSID[]="------";
constexpr char WIFI_PASSWORD[]="-------";

constexpr char THINGSBOARD_SERVER[]="----------";

constexpr char TOKEN[]="Gqeu01FMcrZUhtvVJSpW";

constexpr uint16_t THINGSBOARD_PORT=1883U;

constexpr uint32_t MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE=256U;

constexpr uint32_t SERIAL_DEBUG_BAUD= 115200U;

WiFiClient wifiClient;

Servo myservo;

ThingsBoard tb(wifiClient, MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);

constexpr char FINESTRA_MODE_ATTR[]="finestraMode";

bool subscribed = false;

volatile bool attributesChanged = false;

volatile int finestraMode = 0;  

uint32_t previousStateChange;

int posVal=0; //variable to store servo position

constexpr int16_t telemetrySendInterval = 2000U;
uint32_t previousDataSend;


void InitWiFi() {   
  Serial.println("Connecting to AP ..."); 
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD); 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  IPAddress myIP=WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println("Connected to AP");
  Serial.println(myIP);
}

const bool reconnect() {
  const wl_status_t status = WiFi.status();
  if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {
    return true;
  }
  InitWiFi();
  return true;
}

RPC_Response processSetFinestraMode(const RPC_Data &data){
  Serial.println("Recieved the setFinestraMode RPC method");
  int new_mode=data;
  Serial.print("window mode has changed");
  

  if (new_mode!=0 && new_mode!=1) {
    return RPC_Response("error", "Unknown mode!");
  }

  finestraMode = new_mode;
  attributesChanged = true;

  //returning current mode
  return RPC_Response("newMode",(int)finestraMode);
}

const std::array<RPC_Callback, 1U> callbacks = {
  RPC_Callback{"setFinestraMode", processSetFinestraMode}
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myservo.setPeriodHertz(50);
  myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN,500,2500);
  delay(1000);
  InitWiFi();
}

void loop() {
  if (!reconnect()) {  
    subscribed = false;
    return; 
  }

  if (!tb.connected()) {
    subscribed = false;
    // Connect to the ThingsBoard
    Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
    Serial.print(THINGSBOARD_SERVER);
    Serial.print(" with token ");
    Serial.println(TOKEN);
    if (!tb.connect(THINGSBOARD_SERVER, TOKEN, THINGSBOARD_PORT)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to connect");
      return;   
    }
  }

  if (!subscribed) {
    Serial.println("Subscribing for RPC...");

    if (!tb.RPC_Subscribe(callbacks.cbegin(),callbacks.cend())) {
      Serial.println("Failed to subscribe for RPC");
      return;
    }

    Serial.println("Subscribe done");
    subscribed=true;
  }  

  if (attributesChanged) {
    attributesChanged=false;   

    if (finestraMode==0) {
      for(posVal=0; posVal<=180; posVal+=1) {
        myservo.write(posVal);
        delay(15);
      }
    }

    if (finestraMode==1) {
      for(posVal=180; posVal>=0; posVal-=1) {
        myservo.write(posVal);
        delay(15);
      }
    }
  }

  tb.loop();
}
```

[this is what I did on the control widget on my dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuHcj.jpg)

I want to use the servo to open and close a window when I push the button on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use serial debugging to print debug messages at various stages of your code. This will help you trace where the code might be failing.

Add Serial.println() statements in your code before connecting to Wi-Fi, before subscribing to RPC, and within the RPC callback function.

Also, check if your ESP32 is otherwise functioning well or not. If you ever consider prototyping an ESP32-S3 board by yourself, you can try this design:

https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/ESP32_S2_Module_20b8d465.html